# Set a navigation button for the title of a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to make a standard navigation bar button for my bar's title.  I can set a custom view.  In the sample below, I've done this with a UILabel.  But I don't see how to make a standard navigation button.

```
-(void) setTitleButtonWithText: (NSString*) text {
    self.title = text;
    UIFont* font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font];
    size.width+=6;
    size.height+=6;
    UILabel* titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
    frame.size = size;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
    titleLabel.frame = frame;
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    titleLabel.text = text;
    titleLabel.font = font;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titleView` is a `UIView` property, so since `UIBarButtonItem` is not a `UIView` it cant be used here, as an alternative you could try making a `UIButton` with the same style and set that as the `titleView`

Comment: The problem is the "same style" part.  I could create it from scratch.  Can that really be the right thing to do?

Comment: what do you mean by right?, since you cant assign it directly you need a work-around, using a UIButton seems the best to me